# IPython help functionality in ipdb debugger

Tags: python, debugging, ipython, ipdb

Help is available in a standard IPython shell via the **help** command or by using the **?** character.  For example, for help on the built-in **sum** function, either of the below commands in an IPython shell could be used.

```
In [1]: help(sum)
Help on built-in function sum in module builtin:
...

In [2]: sum?
Signature: sum(iterable, start=0, /)
Docstring: ...
```

I want to have the same functionality in an **ipdb** debugger.  One enters an **ipdb** debugger by placing the below code at the location for a debug breakpoint.

```
from ipdb import set_trace
set_trace()
```

However, once inside the **ipdb** debugger the Help functions no longer work.

```
ipdb> help(sum)
*** No help for '(sum)'
ipdb> sum?
*** SyntaxError: invalid syntax
ipdb>
```

[Help in IPython shell and ipdb debugger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r7gb0.png)

The below command represents a way to print a docstring inside the **ipdb** debugger, however this is not exactly the same functionality as **help(sum)** and **sum?** in the IPython shell.

```
ipdb> print(sum.__doc__)
```

How then do I get the same help functionality in an ipdb debugger that exists in the IPython shell?

Comment: Interesting that you don't get `help`, as that's a python builtin.

Comment: Ah. `help help` you may find useful.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It looks like you can preface it with a `!` (which is short for `exec`)

```
ipdb> !help(sum)
Help on built-in function sum in module builtins:

sum(iterable, start=0, /)
    Return the sum of a 'start' value (default: 0) plus an iterable of numbers

    When the iterable is empty, return the start value.
    This function is intended specifically for use with numeric values and may
    reject non-numeric types.
(END)
```